# Making a char string from char[ ] and int

Tags: c, string

What I'm trying to do is create a single string str out of two variables, so that I can use various string.h functions on it.
This is what I got so far, but it's returning a null string.

```
size_t length = strlen(name) + sizeof(int) + 1;
char *player = malloc(length);
snprintf(player, length, "%s %d\n", name, score);
```

and given another string with the same formatting I then use strcmp on them, like this:

```
if (strcmp(line, player) < 0)
        {
            fprintf(fcopy, "%s %d\n", name, score);

        }
        else
        {
            fputs(line, fcopy);
        }
```

The function I'm trying to write takes the "line" inputs from a txt file structured like this:

*John 50*

*Aaron 45*

So I need the player string to have the same format.
Hope that was clear, I'm sorry but I'm a total newbie and I just started getting into C and using stackoverflow.

Comment: Replace `sizeof(int)` with 3 (for numbers up to 999) and `+ 1` with `+ 2` because of the space before number.

Comment: `sizeof` is the count of bytes a variable takes in memory. It's not the length of the string when a variable is printed in base 10 using digits. Also the `\n` and the space  are characters too that need space in the destination string.

Comment: It works! Thanks for the suggested fixes, now I malloc'd the right memory. I'm not sure what was causing the errors though, since I also rewrote the function from scratch because of a bug.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using dynamic allocation, the easiest is just to let `snprintf` give you the length:

```
// calling with NULL,0 and it returns the count of character that
// __would__ have been written to the buffer
int len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s %d\n", name, score);
char *player = malloc(len + 1);
snprintf(player, len, "%s %d\n", name, score);
...
free(player); // remember to pick out the trash
```

Comment: Forgot to mention I had already tried that, and it gave me an "illegal instruction 4" error code. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If you're using GNU or BSD libs, you can also use `asprintf(&player, "%s %d\n", name, score);` to do it all in one line.